# How can I specify cobertura report path for gradle sonar-runner plugin?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to convert my configuration from the old gradle 'sonar' plugin to the new gradle 'sonar-runner' plugin for gradle 1.5.

Since I switched to the sonar-runner plugin, sonar is no longer reusing my cobertura coverage.xml to calculate unit test coverage.  I can't find any examples in the [sonar-runner user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html) showing how to configure this.  Previously I was using the sonar.project.coberturaReportPath to specify the location of my coverage.xml.

My sonar instance is v.3.4.  I'm using a gradle cobertura plugin to generate my coverage.xml.

Here's my sonar-runner configuration:

```
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties{
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://sonar:3306/sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.username", "username"
        property "sonar.password", "password"
        property "sonar.language", "grvy"
        property "sonar.coberturaReportPath", file("$buildDir/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml") //not sure if this is right!
    }
}
```

Here's my old sonar configuration (which worked!):

```
sonar {
    server {
        url = "http://sonar"
    }
    database {
        url = "jdbc:mysql://sonar:3306/sonar"
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "username"
        password = "password"
    }
    project {
        language = "grvy"
        coberturaReportPath = file("$buildDir/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure to use the correct Sonar properties. From http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project:

```
sonarRunner {
    ...
    sonarProperty "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "cobertura"
    sonarProperty "sonar.cobertura.reportPath", file(...)
}
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick!  I didn't need to specify sonar.java.coveragePlugin since I have cobertura set as the default in sonar, but it's probably a good idea to set it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I was using:

- Gradle 1.5
- Sonar 3.4.1
- [Sonar Groovy Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Groovy+Plugin) 0.6

and I could not get it work. Sonar was displaying the "-" instead of the percentage of covered code.

I found this [JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2127) which should be fixed in [Sonar Groovy Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Groovy+Plugin) 1.0, if you have the same problem as I had and that the 1.0 is released already, an update may fix the problem.

Or else, there is a workaround discussed in [this topic](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/code_coverage_reports_cobertura_jacoco_are_not_being_pushed_to_sonar):

- Download the [Spantree fork](https://github.com/Spantree/sonar-groovy) of the Sonar Groovy Plugin
- Unzip and build (`mvn install` in the root of the `sonar-groovy-master` project)
- Copy `sonar-groovy-plugin-1.0-spantree-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the `extensions/plugins` subdirectory of your Sonar installation directory
- Remove or alter the extension of the old `sonar-groovy-plugin-0.6.jar`
- Restart sonar and try `gradle sonarRunner` again